# Android secure RestAPI using Google Account OAuth

Tags: android, rest, oauth, google-account

How can I secure our RestAPI in Android using Google Account?

Raw steps would be great. I can imagine how a user can connect to its Google Account - http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html#AccountPicker .

I don't know how to continue after... Any ideas? At least raw steps would be gr8. It doesn't have to be anything detailed.

Thank you,
Zat

Answer (score 1):

You can secure your API like Kinvey api do

[image]

you can implement your own like above image 
I think this tutorial will help you to secure your rest API,

[link](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/security)

I hope this will solve your problem. good luck.

Comment: Thx for a quick answer kuhrram! I will try it and get back to accept if I use this way.

Comment: I wish a Good luck Zatziky :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the way. I modified the Title. I need it to do it using Google Account.